# C# application exception void to string

Tags: c#

I am really new to C# and i am trying to write a very basic scraper in a Console Appliciation however i get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type void to string
```

What i am trying to do in the below code is set the returned input as a variable and return that variable to my Main method. so that the Main Method can access and read the returned value to be displayed if needed.

```
private static string setTargetModule()
{
    string targetUrl = Console.Write("Target: http://");
    return targetUrl;
}
```

Comment: `Console.Write()` doesn't return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *problem* is that `Console.Write("Target: http://")` has does not return anything, since it is `void`.

To go around this, you will need to output the text onto the screen and then explicitely read it back. Thus, your code would become:

```
private static string setTargetModule()
{
    Console.Write("Target: http://");
    string targetUrl = Console.ReadLine();
    return targetUrl;
}
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
private static string setTargetModule()
{
    Console.Write("Target: http://");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: OOHH, that makes alot of sense :) Thanks for that

Comment: @Elevant: You're welcome. Also for the record, C# standard dictates that method names start with an uppeer case letter, thus `setTargetModule` would become `SetTargetModule`

Comment: Okay thanks for that i will incorporate that standard :) very helpful

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write("Target: http://")` returns nothing,It just writes to a `Console` . That is a `void`. You cannot assign `void` to a `string`

Answer (score 1):

Use three lines instead of two:

```
string targetUrl = "Target: http://";
Console.Write(targetUrl);
return targetUrl;
```

You need to set the string `"Target: http://"` to a variable **before** writing to the console, because Console.Write() returns type void: 
`void Console.Write(string value)`

The original code is basically this: `string targetUrl = void;`